# How to safely output user input HTML in a twig theme

Tags: 10

Very basic question:

I have a twig template were I want to output the HTML content of a CkEditor managed field within a node.

```
<div class="wrap-user-html">
  {{ node.field_myfield.0.value }}
</div>
```

This does not work, as it prints the html code with html entities.
I'm getting e. g.

```
<div class="wrap-user-html">
  &lt;p&gt;foo&lt;/p&gt;
</div>
```

I could use |raw and it would work, but I read this is unsafe. Also when using raw, text format filters from the ckeditor settings seem to not get applied.

How do I do this right?

Comment: I saw this question and its answer, but didn't get how this translates to the output of a simple field value... if this answers my question, would you be so kind to show me how to set the variable for my example in twig?

Answer (score 2):

Thanx to the comment of user [cilefen](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/17684/cilefen) I finally got it:

instead of

```
<div class="wrap-user-html">
  {{ node.field_myfield.0.value|raw }}
</div>
```

it would be

```
  {% set wysiwgcontent = {
    '#type': 'processed_text',
    '#text': node.field_myfield.0.value,
    '#format': node.field_myfield.0.format,
  } %}
  {{ wysiwgcontent }}
```

Comment: Normally you would get the format from the same field: `node.field_myfield.0.format`

Comment: oc, I corrected the example code, ty.